# Finding State Short Name from JSON file with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file that have all list of all the countries with their cities, and state. The file has this structure

```
  "NO": {
"name": "Norway",
"states": {
  "VA": {
    "name": "Vest-Agder"
  },
  "RO": {
    "name": "Rogaland"
  },
  "HO": {
    "name": "Hordaland"
  },
  "SF": {
    "name": "Sogn og Fjordane"
  },
  "MR": {
    "name": "Møre og Romsdal"
  },
  "ST": {
    "name": "Sør-Trøndelag"
  },
  "NO": {
    "name": "Nord-Trøndelag"
  },
  "NT": {
    "name": "Nordland"
  },
  "TR": {
    "name": "Troms"
  },
  "FI": {
    "name": "Finnmark"
  },
  "SJ": {
    "name": "Svalbard"
  },
  "SJ": {
    "name": "Jan Mayen"
  },
  "AK": {
    "name": "Akershus"
  },
  "AA": {
    "name": "Aust-Agder"
  },
  "BU": {
    "name": "Buskerud"
  },
  "HE": {
    "name": "Hedmark"
  },
  "OP": {
    "name": "Oppland"
  },
  "OS": {
    "name": "Oslo"
  },
  "TE": {
    "name": "Telemark"
  },
  "VF": {
    "name": "Vestfold"
  },
  "OF": {
    "name": "Østfold"
  }
}
```

},

What I am trying to achieve is to get the short name of state when user input the full name in the input field. For example if they add "Oslo" I will get "OS" in output

This is the code that I came up with but I am not getting the output.

```
     $jsonitem = file_get_contents("countries-info.json");
 $objitems = json_decode($jsonitem);
$findByname = function($name) use ($objitems) {
    foreach ($objitems as $friend) {
        if ($friend->name == $name) return $friend->state;
     }

    return false;
};
echo $findByname($_GET[code]) ?: 'No record found.';
```

Need advise.

Comment: Is it working and you just want a faster algorithm?

Comment: @davidev no the code that I am trying is not working. Do you have any suggestion to fix or like you said is there any improved (faster) way of getting the required output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the structure of your JSON you should loop `$objitems->NO->states` ( `$objitems` will contain the complete object, you only want the `states`)

So you need to change your `foreach` to:

```
 foreach ($objitems->NO->states as $short => $state) {
    if ($state->name == $name) return $short;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks you mate, this is what exactly I was thinking but not able to write the code. your solution fixes my problem :)

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($objitems as $state => $friend) {
    if ($friend->name == $name) return $state;
 }
```

Comment: your code is not working in case of sending full state name "Oslo". Its giving output of Country short code, like when I send Norway, I get NO as output. What I need is to get state short name e.g I pass Oslo and get OS as output

Comment: then you have to loop  states by the same logic